# I am trying to use Curl::Easy.http_put but have some issues with the data argument

Tags: ruby, http-put, curb

I'm struggling with a ruby script to upload some pictures to moodstocks using their http interface

here is the code that I have so far

```
curb = Curl::Easy.new
curb.http_auth_types = :digest
curb.username = MS_API
curb.password = MS_SECRET
curb.multipart_form_post = true

Dir.foreach(images_directory) do |image|
  if image.include? '.jpg'
    path = images_directory + image
    filename = File.basename(path, File.extname(path))

    puts "Upload #{path} with id #{filename}"

    raw_url = 'http://api.moodstocks.com/v2/ref/' + filename
    encoded_url = URI.parse URI.encode raw_url

    curb.url = encoded_url
    curb.http_put(Curl::PostField.file('image_file', path))
  end
end
```

and this is the error that I get

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/curb-0.8.5/lib/curl/easy.rb:57:in `add': no implicit        conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/curb-0.8.5/lib/curl/easy.rb:57:in `perform'
    from upload_moodstocks.rb:37:in `http_put'
    from upload_moodstocks.rb:37:in `block in <main>'
    from upload_moodstocks.rb:22:in `foreach'
    from upload_moodstocks.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

I think the problem is in how I give the argument to the http_put method, but I have tried to look for some examples of Curl::Easy.http_put and have found nothing so far.

Could anyone point me to some documentation regarding it or help me out on this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here:

**1. URI::HTTP instead of String**

First, the `TypeError` you encounter comes from the fact that you pass a `URI::HTTP` instance (`encoded_url`) as `curb.url` instead of a plain Ruby string.

*You may want to use `encoded_url.to_s`, but the question is why do you do this parse/encode here?*

**2. PUT w/ multipart/form-data**

The second problem is related to [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb). At the time of writing (v0.8.5) curb does **NOT** support the ability to perform a HTTP PUT request with `multipart/form-data` encoding.

If you refer to the source code you can see that:

1. the [`multipart_form_post`](https://github.com/taf2/curb/blob/a3b2594/ext/curb_easy.c#L2307) setting is only used for POST requests,
2. the [`put_data`](https://github.com/taf2/curb/blob/a3b2594/ext/curb_easy.c#L756) setter does not support `Curl::PostField`-s

---

To solve your problem you need an HTTP client library that can combine Digest Authentication, multipart/form-data and HTTP PUT.

In Ruby you can use [rufus-verbs](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-verbs), but you will need to use [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) to build the multipart body.

There is also [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) but it has issues with Digest Auth.

That is why I greatly recommend to go ahead with Python and use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
import os

MS_API_KEY = "kEy"
MS_API_SECRET = "s3cr3t"

filename = "sample.jpg"

with open(filename, "r") as f:
  base = os.path.basename(filename)
  uid = os.path.splitext(base)[0]

  r = requests.put(
    "http://api.moodstocks.com/v2/ref/%s" % uid,
    auth = HTTPDigestAuth(MS_API_KEY, MS_API_SECRET),
    files = {"image_file": (base, f.read())}
  )

  print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, in the end I solved the issue by calling the curl command from ruby using the 'system' command